# Start a docker container from bash script and execute commands on it

Tags: bash, docker

I am having a problem running Fenics using their docker container:

Background to this is: One main VM communicates with the user via a REST API and gets one or many tasks to compute in Fenics. Fenics runs on the docker containers. Now the main VM has to orchestrate different worker-VMs using a script.

Example: the user wants to have meshes A and B getting computed using  parameter sets x and y. For this two worker-VMs can be used, which have Fenics container installed. How can I start a docker container and pass the parameters into it, by using a bash script?

In the first try I cannot even access a created container on my own computer using a script, since the container exits immediately.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
docker run -dit -v $(pwd):/home/fenics/shared -w /home/fenics/shared quay.io/fenicsproject/stable:curre$

OUTPUT=$(docker ps -q | grep "$name")
echo $OUTPUT
docker exec -dit $OUTPUT /bin/bash
docker exec -dit $OUTPUT echo "Hallo"
docker exec -dit $OUTPUT mkdir test
docker exec -dit $OUTPUT echo "Ciao"
```

If I look into `docker ps -a` I can only see exited containers.

Two questions arise therefore: Firstly, is this the way to pass the commands appropriately and secondly, how can I keep the container running?

As might be obvious, I have no prior experience using docker and am therefore grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

most likely, what you want to do is put your commands into a file `commands.sh` and then run `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/home/fenics/shared -w /home/fenics/share --entrypoint bash quay.io/fenicsproject/stable:current commands.sh`

What this will do is share your folder, launch the fenics container, and execute the shell script inside that container (presumably, your output will write to a file in the shared drive). The `--rm` part will clean up the container after the run.

I don't actually know what fenics is- if there is some sort of state or initialization, make sure you are taking care of that in your commands.sh file, since over-riding the entrypoint will prevent any fancy init scripts they provided from running. Alternatively, their docker image repo may explain how to feed a custom script to the container.

Comment: Fenics ist just a platform for differential equations and other mathematical stuff. Our workflow should look like this somehow.
First:
- User sends Parameters to Host (we are doing finite elements here)
- Host distributes tasks to several VMs that are running already
Second:
- Start the container?
- Worker-VM sends params to Fenics Container
- Fenics computes the solution
- Worker VM gets result out of the Container
- Close the container

Therefore I do not know if my idea above is in anyway a good solution to get the computation done.

Comment: The communication can happen in the same ways that any set of processes communicate with one another- they can send API requests, TCP through a socket, or use a filesystem (there's probably more) - but being in a container doesn't change that in any way. I don't actually understand WHY you would want to run multiple processes for the same computation in multiple containers. It seems likely that the program itself handles threading and interpoc communication much better than a bash script + docker?

Comment: Each computation takes approximately an hour. Since we have some virtual machines that we can use, it would be better to distribute 8 computations on lets say 4 machines: so two hours per machine compared to one with 8 hours workload

Comment: Right, but what you described is running multiple containers on one machine, which seems unlikely to actually improve performance. If you are instead planning on running remote processes, you are going to need a lot more in-depth knowledge, mostly of the API of the program you are working with.

Comment: Sorry yes the virtual machines are actually ubuntu machines in an OpenStack cloud, not VMs on my computer. The "big goal" would be dynamical scalability ... though I would be happy with static machines for now

Comment: Yeah, sorry- setting up a distributed computing cluster from scratch with no domain knowledge is gonna be beyond the scope of a SO answer :)

Comment: Well the network stands (it is from the university), I have set up a distributed system with RabbitMQ and Celery under Python just days ago, that is definitely not the question :)
I just have absolutely no experience with bash scripts and so on ^^